# Why is react not letting me use a router dom Link inside of an html list item?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have the following Link within a html list item and I am getting an error.

```
<li className="nav-item">
  <Link to={'/cart'}>
    <i
      className="fa fa-shopping-bag"
      style={{fontSize: "22px"}}></i>
  </Link>
</li>
```

The error:

```
index.tsx:19 Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

Comment: And ... where is your `<Router>` element around it? If you are making an SPA use `<Router>` and `<Link>` otherwise just use `<a href=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because somewhere, farther up on the tree you did not wrap your components in a router component, which is required to make react router work.

See: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing